# Port forwarding - wired thing

Tags: port, router, forwarding

This is my first post here and i hope that someone can help me

I opened 2 different ports on the router for two different ip's

When i check the port 1300 (this port is for laptop #1) it says the port is open

But when I check the port 1400 (this port is for the #2 laptop) it says the port isn't open

Both laptops os is windows 10 and firewall disabled (tried to enable then check , the same problem)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Come on guys anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything listening to the port 1400? Without service active it will probably not return anything and shows as inactive / timed out.

Use cmd (on windows) as administrator and type:

```
netstat -aon | more
```

to see which ports are listening.